# Choosing the mos to replace the other mos which i don't have

Tags: components, nmos

If i  don't have the "A" NMOS,how do i know the "B" NMOS can replace it ? For example,here is the "A"NMOS product summary,if the BVdss min(V) is 60V for "B"NMOS too ,Can B replace A?

[image]

Comment: How should we know what your requirements for the MOS are? These are just infos about what you have, not what you need.

Comment: Critical specs are RdsOn and Vgs(th) to ensure T['C] rise is acceptible

Comment: Ciss may matter too. A lot. And Crss.

Comment: This actually is a valid question if you think about it - it's a question about the design process and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you first choose a MOSFET (or any component) for a design, you should consider: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate MOSFETs (or any component)

When you **replace** that MOSFET (or any component) with another, you should consider: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate MOSFETs (or any component)

So, no visible circuit to study means no clear understanding of: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance

And no clear idea of what MOSFET (or any component) can be chosen

Comment: @electroniccomponent Have you understood this answer?